# Has anyone used Chris van de Steeg's compiling of Razor views technique in production?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Chris van de Steeg recently detailed and implemented a means to precompile your Razor views into a separate DLL: [Embedding precompiled razor views in your dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll). Has anyone made use of this technique in a production environment and if so are your experiences positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't, but another approach worth looking into is one by David Ebbo, an architect on the ASP.NET team: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html

Comment: I am using this now and it freakin' rocks!